# Match only the first paragraph using bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

#### We have

...a file containing paragraphs, splitted by 2 newlines `\r\n\r\n` or `\n\n`. The paraghraphs themselves may contain single newlines `\r\n` or `\n`. The goal is to use a Bash one-liner to  match **only** the first paragraph and to print it to stdout.

#### E.G.:

```sh
$ cat foo.txt
Foo
* Bar

Baz
* Foobar

Even more stuff to match here.
```

results in:

```sh
$ cat foo.txt | <some-command>
Foo
* Bar
```

#### I've already tried

...this regex `(?s)(.+?)(\r?\n){2}|.+?$` with `grep` using

- GIT Bash on Windows (GNU grep 3.1),
- Bash on Lubuntu 20.4.1 LTS (GNU grep 3.4) and
- iTerm+Fish on Mac (BSD grep 2.5.1-FreeBSD).

The first two approaches resulted in:

```sh
$ grep -Poz '(?s)(.+?)(\r?\n){2}|.+?$' foo.txt
Foo                                                                                                                          
* Bar

Baz                                                                                                                          
* Foobar
```

The approach on Mac failed, due to differences between BSD grep and GNU grep.

#### But

... on regex101.com this regex works on foo.txt: https://regex101.com/r/uoej8O/1. This may be due to disabling the `global` flag?

Comment: When you say _"may contain single newlines \r\n or \n."_ do you mean you have a mix of the two types of line endings in one file? Or that you need this to work on normal files, some of which have DOS line endings, and some of which have Unix line endings?

Comment: @jas Because of DOS and UNIX endings.

Comment: It is always safer to remove DOS line ending before using any Unix shell tools as it may give unexpected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a GNU `grep` like this:

```sh
grep -Poz '(?s)^.+?(?=\R{2}|$)' file
```

See the [***PCRE* regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/BkuGDy/2).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL inline modifier that makes `.` match all chars including linebreak chars
- `^` - start of the whole string
- `.+?` - any 1 or more chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\R{2}|$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with a double line break sequence (`\R{2}`) or end of string (`$`).

Answer (score 8):

This is a **tailor-made problem for `gnu awk`** by using a custom record separator. We can use a custom `RS` that breaks file data by 2 or more of an optional `\r` followed by `\n`:

```sh
awk -v RS='(\r?\n){2,}' 'NR == 1' file
```

This outputs:

```
Foo
* Bar
```

If you want `awk` to be more efficient when input is very big:

```sh
awk -v RS='(\r?\n){2,}' '{print; exit}' file
```

Answer (score 5):

For GNU awk if the paragraphs are separated by `\r\n\r\n` or `\n\n`:

```
$ awk -v RS="\r?\n\r?\n" '{print $0;exit}' file
```

Output:

```
Foo
* Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first paragraph and the paragraphs are separated by a newline, then this might work:

```
awk '!NF{ exit } 1' foo.txt
```

Comment: Along the same lines:  `awk '$0=="" { exit }1' foo.txt`

Comment: Instead of `$0==""` I suggest `awk '!NF { print; exist }' foo.txt`

Comment: This too fails if the first paragraph is separated by `\r\n\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;P;/\n\r\?$/Q;D' file
```

Open a two line window, print the first of these lines and if the window contains a newline (with an optional return) at the end of a line, quit processing (without printing anything else).